# What are the costs of having multiple/alternate spellbooks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I know wizards can get a certain number of spells in their spellbook for free as they level up, but does that specifically cover having them written down in *one* spellbook? If you plan to maintain a second or so spellbook or record your spells by some means other than specifically a spell*book*, does that incur extra costs to record spells across multiple sources, whether as duplicates or just kept separately on different media (e.g. book, bone fragments, and/or tattoo?)

Comment: Preemptively protecting because spammers love the keywords you used.

Comment: It is considered a smart and common practice for Wizards to have more than one spellbook. Usually, one is hidden soemwhere as a backup in their things and perhaps they have gotten one hidden unde rtheir favourite inn room's floorboards etc. You can also share out yoru spells with fellow Wizards and swap spells with them also. the cost being the componenets to copy the spell. Also, scrolls can be used to get a copy of a spell, usually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Spells On Levelup**

[You get those spells in a spellbook, by RAW](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#wizard):

> At each new wizard level, she gains two new spells of any spell level
>   or levels that she can cast (based on her new wizard level) for her
>   spellbook

But, you don't have to put them all in the same book. In fact, [a standard spellbook only has 100 pages](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#spellbookWizardsBlank), and each spell takes a page per spell level. So you'll likely run out of pages and have multiple books, or make the investment in a [Blessed Book](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#blessedBook).

"For her spellbook" implies to me you only get it for free in one book, though it doesn't say so outright (it also doesn't say you get them in 17 books). [If you want to make dupliate copies of a spell, there's rules for that](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/arcaneSpells.htm#replacingandCopyingSpellbooks):

> A wizard can use the procedure for learning a spell to reconstruct a
>   lost spellbook. If she already has a particular spell prepared, she
>   can write it directly into a new book at a cost of 100 gp per page (as
>   noted in Writing a New Spell into a Spellbook, above). The process
>   wipes the prepared spell from her mind, just as casting it would. If
>   she does not have the spell prepared, she can prepare it from a
>   borrowed spellbook and then write it into a new book.
>
> Duplicating an existing spellbook uses the same procedure as replacing
>   it, but the task is much easier. The time requirement and cost per
>   page are halved.

**Does a spellbook have to be a book?**

A spellbook is an actual item in the item list, and is mentioned numerous times specifically. You could interpret that to mean it has to be a book.

That said, Complete Arcane has rules for differing types of books. A book made of something else is still a book, and the cost of copying the spells is the same unless CArc says otherwise. For something like bone fragments, it doesn't: the extra cost is in buying a book made of that material.

So yes, in that case your free spells could go into anything that counts as a spellbook in that way. On something else, it becomes undefined and is up to your DM.

Comment: In terms of using an actual book I'd like to say that, as a GM, I wouldn't care what fluff a PC uses as long as it uses the same mechanics. Store your spells as ideas in a crystal, but you have to treat it as a 100 page spellbook. Just a thought.

Comment: There are actually rules in Complete Arcane for using a bag of sling stones or bone fragments or even tattooing your body as a means of recording spells. Some of these actually incur different costs for recording spells that way; I was actually kind of wondering if the "free spells" bypassed those costs too.

Comment: @Cobalt Ah, I see. Updated in regards to that. In general if it's something that has a price to get or a rule about using it as a book, you should be fine. If you just invent something, then it's up to your DM as it's not defined anywhere.